# Android: Google Maps V2 no compatible devices running

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-2.3-gingerbread

First I configured an AVD using the following settings:

- Device: 3.7", 480x800: hdpi
- Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 10
- RAM: 512
- VM Heap: 32
- SD Card: 10 MiB
- Emulation Options: Snapshot

I'm trying to run a simple map. The AVD is running, but when I try to run the app it says: "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device?" android-support-v4.jar is in my libs folder.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maps.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="#################################"/>
</application>
```

Here's my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main" >

<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my Main.java

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is your project build target? make sure it have to be google api

Comment: The min sdk is 10. The build target is Google APIs sdk 18.

Comment: The more I read this, the more I'm realizing that it looks like I can't run this on an emulator. Apparently Maps v2 requires play services which won't run on an emulator. This is stupid. I need to support devices going back to gingerbread. In order to test that I need emulation support.

Comment: In order to make it actually accept the AVD I had to change the build target to Google APIs for SDK 10. Once I did that it loaded, but it says it can't run on a phone without google play services which can't be installed on an emulator running anything less that 4.2.2. So I'll say it again, how is a developer supposed to check for compatibility when he/she can't run the app on an older emulator?